# TableView inside Tableview ios

Tags: swift, iphone, uitableview

I am using tableview inside tableview cell. My main tableview is using Array1 to make no of rows and inside each row there is another tableview. now i have two different arrays Array2 and Array3.

How to populate data from Array2 for main tableview cell0 and populate data from Array3 for main tableview cell1?

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say tableView1’s first cell is Cell1, Second cell is Cell2

Cell1 have tableView2 and
Cell2 have tableView3

1) In cellForRowAt of tableView1, reload the child table that it contains.

```
   if indexPath.row == 0 {
         let  cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
         “Cell1”,for: indexPath) as! Cell1
          -----
        //your code
          -----
         cell1.tableView2.reloadData()
         return cell1
    } else {
         let  cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “Cell2”, 
         for: indexPath) as! Cell2
          -----
        //your code
          -----
         cell2.tableView3.reloadData()
         return cell2

    }
```

2) Implement respective DataSource and delegates in Cell1 and Cell2.